lm-evaluation-harness with LoRa fine tuned models Hugging Face
!python -m lm_eval 
--model hf 
--model_args pretrained=theoracle/gemma_italian_camoscio 
--tasks xcopa_it,hellaswag_it,lambada_openai_mt_it,belebele_ita_Latn,arc_it 
--device cuda:0 
--batch_size 8
I Want to use on my model theoracle/gemma_italian_camoscio it is a quantised and LORA meodel but when I try to load it does not appear to have a file named config.json
I understand that when using auto train I might have saved only the weights, is there any approach to have this working?
I wantt to evaluate the llm, getting the error as indicated above

I faced with something similar when evaluating a model that I fine-tuned using Lora.
Here in their documentation: https://github.com/EleutherAI/lm-evaluation-harness?tab=readme-ov-file#advanced-usage-tips
they suggest how to use lm_eval when evaluating on a peft model: you should add in pretrained the model used for tuning and add peft=<PEFT_MODEL_NAME> into the model_args.

try this:
python -m lm_eval \
    --model hf \
    --model_args pretrained=/root/autodl-tmp/models/Meta-Llama-3-8B/LLM-Research/Meta-Llama-3-8B,peft=/root/autodl-tmp/codes/qwen_stf/.llama/final_model_r_4 \
    --batch_size 8 \
    --tasks mmlu\
    --device cuda:0 \
    --output_path ../results

replace peft path with your lora saved path
